# Showing nodes grouped by taxonomy with views

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

need to display the content like this

## Taxonomy Term 1:

Node1
Title:
Body:

Node 2
Title:
Body:

## Taxonomy Term 2:

Node 3:
Title:
Body:

Node 4:
Title:
Body

I have content under the taxonomy terms. How could I display content in the above format using views or without it.

I actually got the answer http://tiger-fish.com/blog/drupal-6-grouping-and-theming-nodes-under-taxonomy-single-page here (its for drupal 6 but similar stuff for 7).

The problem now is that I can't display the page by embedding the view. the content have a 'load more' option to load more content under a taxonomy via ajax.  so I was using views_view_get_result() method to load the result in a custom module and pass it on to the the ajax calling function , I can do that successfully when there is no taxonomy grouping. Just can't get to display the results in a grouped by taxonomy format via php code.

I hope I made myself clear

Answer (score 2):

You must use the group option in the style display. In group option you must select the field taxonomy term. And then you must Exclude from display the field taxonomy term.